# kendo grid using html heplers

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

- I am new to loading the kendo controls using html helpers in razor.
- I am trying to load kendo grid.
- I am not able to load the grid content.

In the view side, I have defined like:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoStarted.Models.Products>().Name("grid").DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("grid_KendoHelper_Data1", "Product_Data_"))).Columns(columns => { columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName); columns.Bound(p => p.ProductID);columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice ); }) )
```

and in the controller side I have given like

```
public ActionResult grid_KendoHelper_Data1([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request) 
{
    using (var ent = new EntitiesModel())
    {
        IQueryable<Product> prdts = ent.Products;
        var product_Data_gridKendoHelp = EntityModObj.Products.Select(i => new { i.ProductID, i.ProductName, i.UnitPrice }).ToArray();
        return Json(product_Data_gridKendoHelp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

I am able to return the values from the controller in the controller side, but I am not able to bind the content.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I have updated,check once

Comment: error event is not accepting,it is showing at the error event  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoStarted.Models.Products>().Name("grid").DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("grid_KendoHelper_Data1", "Product_Data_"))).Columns(columns => { columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName); columns.Bound(p => p.ProductID);columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice ); }).Events(ev=>ev.Error("err_han")) )

Answer (score 1):

append this in your view

```
.Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
```

and write down this in ur script and check what error you getting coz in first look it seems normal to me

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function error_handler(e) {
            if (e.errors) {
                var message = "Errors:\n";
                $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                    if ('errors' in value) {
                        $.each(value.errors, function () {
                            message += this + "\n";
                        });
                    }
                });
                alert(message);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

UPDATE :-

just follow the below pattern in trurning json result

```
 return Json(product_Data_gridKendoHelp.ToDataSourceResult(request));
```